# compute averages using perl

Tags: perl

Is it possible to Write a program that computes averages by asking the user to enter the numbers to be average?

I wrote a perl script that computes the averages of three numbers. Here is my code:

```
#usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $a; #variable declaration
 my $b; #variable declaration
 my $c; #variable declaration
 my $avg; #variable declaration
 my $x; #variable declaration
 my $y; #variable declaration
 my $z; #variable declaration
 my $results; #variable declaration
 my $number; #variable declaration

 $a = 2; #number 1
 $b = 6; #number 2
 $c = 7; #number 3

 $avg = avg($a,$b,$c); #Three variables to be averaged

  sub avg {
  ($x,$y,$z) = @_; #Store variables in array
   $results = ($x+$y+$z)/3; #Values stored added, and divided for average
   return $results; #return value

           }

   print "$avg\n";
   exit;
```

Instead of my code computing averages of numbers i enter into variables i rather be prompted to enter three numbers at the terminal to be averaged out.  I know in perl to do something like that you have to implement some code like so:

```
 print STDOUT "Enter a number: \n";
 $averages = <STDIN>;
 print "The Average is $averages.\n";
```

When i add this to my code it doesn't print anything out how can this be properly implemented to my code.

Comment: If you read the first four chapters of Learning Perl, you'll be able to answer this on your own.

Comment: Sadly I had to vote to close this question. Please read some of the excellent Perl documentation (using the `perldoc` utility or at http://perldoc.perl.org) start at [perlintro](perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html). For "real" books, try Learning Perl (as bdf said) or chromatic's [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) which is available for free. There is even Gabor's [tutorial](http://szabgab.com/perl_tutorial.html). Once you have learned the language basics, we will be happy to help you with your bugs/problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general solution for computing the average could be the first step:

```
sub avg {
    my $total;
    $total += $_ foreach @_;
    # sum divided by number of components.
    return $total / @_;
}
```

That way you don't care how many items you're averaging.  `avg()` figures it out.

The next step is to read your input.  You can do that with the `<>` operator like this:

```
my @input;
print "Enter a few numbers...\n";
while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    while( m/([\d.-])/g ) {
        push @input, $1;
    }
}
local $" = ', ';
print "The average of [@input] is ", avg( @input ), "\n";
```

And at the end we put it all together by printing the set of inputs, and invoking and printing `avg()`.

The regular expression just pulls out things that look vaguely like numbers from a string of input.  It's nothing like a number validator.

Comment: Better from a precision point of view, and better result for no args: `sub avg { my $avg; $avg += $_/@_ for @_; return $avg; }`

Comment: With standard floating point math I found a difference of 2 in the least significant printed digit.  With Math::BigFloat I found a difference of 1.3e-40.  Ysth suggested sorting the input to get the highest magnitude numbers into the mix soonest, but that didn't change the result from what I could detect.  As for returning undef versus throwing an exception, I guess that depends on what you want, but it would be easy enough to return undef before starting any work within the sub.  Interesting suggestion though.  I enjoyed tinkering with several alternate solutions, @ikegami. :)

Comment: It will affect longer sequences, because you'll end up adding small numbers to large numbers, so the lower bits of the small numbers will be totally lost. Yes, the difference will be very minor. Returning undef instead of zero for no input is quite nice, though

Comment: Yes, returning undef is optimal (and easy to arrange for regardless of algorithm).  You might check my PerlMonks scratchpad and follow up there if you see a problem with my test.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $sum = 0;
my $n = 0;
while (<>) {
    $sum += $_;
    $n++;
}
print $sum/$n, "\n";
```

Briefly, we compute the average by summing and keeping track of the number of items. `while (<>)` magically reads either from files specified on the command line or from STDIN (you might want to use `while (<STDIN>)` instead if your program is only interactive).